# How to find presentation of finitely presented monoid on Gap with given conditions

Tags: group-presentation, monoid, gap

Let G be monoid generated by x,y,z,e  with given relations :

```
relations := [ [x^245, e], [y^245, e], [z^245, e], [x^28, y^19*z^9],
[y^31, x^15*z^17], [z^42, x^12*y^7], [x*y, y*x], [x*z, z*x], 
[y*z, z*y]];
```

How to get the elements of G on the format `x^a*y^b*z^c`, such that

1. `x<28`,`y<31`,`z<42` and
2. if `x^a*y^b*z^c` is element of the set also
   `x^(a-1)*y^b*z^c`,
   `x*^a*y^(b-1)*z^c` and
   `x^a*y^b*z^(c-1)`
   must be elements of that set.

I tried to solve considering first conditon but do not know how to define on the code the second condition

```
gap> F := FreeSemigroup("id","x","y","z");
<free semigroup on the generators [ id, x, y, z ]>
gap> id := F.1;; x := F.2;; y := F.3;; z := F.4;;
gap> rels:= [ [x^245, e], [y^245, e], [z^245, e], [x^28, y^19*z^9], [y^31, x^15*z^17], [z^42, x^12*y^7], [x*y, y*x], [x*z, z*x], [y*z, z*y]];;
gap> S := F/rels;
<fp semigroup on the generators [ id, x, y, z ]>
gap> x := S.2; y := S.3; z := S.4;;
x
y
gap> List(Cartesian([1..27],[1..30],[1..41]),t->x^t[1]*y^t[2]*z^t[3]);;
gap> elms := List(Cartesian([1..27],[1..30],[1..41]),t->x^t[1]*y^t[2]*z^t[3]);;
gap> elms := Concatenation(elms,List(Cartesian([1..30],[1..41]),t->y^t[1]*z^t[2]));;
gap> elms := Concatenation(elms,List(Cartesian([1..27],[1..41]),t->x^t[1]*z^t[2]));;
gap> elms := Concatenation(elms,List(Cartesian([1..27],[1..30]),t->x^t[1]*y^t[2]));;
gap> cls := EquivalenceClasses(elms,\=);;
gap> Length(cls);
245
```

Comment: If `e` is the identity, why do you make it an extra generator?

Comment: Is it clear that you can describe the 245 elements of the monoid in the required form without duplicates?

Comment: Thanx e lot dear professor Alexander Hulpke. I think must be 245 different elements on the set since there are 245 different elements on G

Comment: Yes, there are 245 elements. But your condition on also including word with reduced exponents might cause the same element to be represented twice.

Comment: Thanx a lot dear professor, what do you think I should change on the code to get solution, please

Answer (score 1):

You have a group (every generator is invertible) that is abelian (generators commute).

Considering the relator matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}%
245&0&0\\%
0&245&0\\%
0&0&245\\%
28&-19&-9\\%
-15&31&-17\\%
-12&-7&42\\%
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we get (using `t:=SmithNormalFormIntegerMatTransforms(m)`) a Smith normal form `t.normal` of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}%
1&0&0\\%
0&1&0\\%
0&0&245\\%
0&0&0\\%
0&0&0\\%
0&0&0\\%
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with column transformations `t.coltrans`
$$
\begin{pmatrix}%
1&0&-91\\%
0&1&-83\\%
0&0&1\\%
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This shows that the group is cyclic, generated by $z$, and that $x=z^{-91}$ and $y=z^{-83}$.

Comment: Thanx a lot dear professor, still can not make connection how to continue to solve the exercise, sorry